# Epic Games - GTA 5 download speed stuck at 0

Tags: pc, grand-theft-auto-v, epic-games-launcher

I started downloading GTA V on EPIC GAMES. After a while I was getting a constant 0 speed with minor spikes. It's been 4 days and the speed is still stagnant.
What should I do ?

[image]

Comment: Is the connection blocked by your firewall, maybe? Since corona the download speeds have been throttled (of which I see no prompt here) - Epic might have changed some settings.

Comment: Can you download other games from the epic store without an issue?  What about from other stores, like Steam?  When you say it's been like this for 4 days, has it been open the whole time?  Maybe try closing the Epic Launcher (even rebooting the computer) and restarting the download.  It's possible - especially given how heavy the traffic was for this particular game - that your initial connection was just dropped in a way that the Epic Launcher doesn't know how to report properly, and so it just sits there.

Comment: Epic had quite a problem with everybody getting their free copy of GTA 5, bringing their servers to their knees. Things should be fairly OK again, but the outage could have potentially corrupted your download. Did you try to redownload it?

Answer (score 1):

After comparing how the download speed reacts after decreasing/increasing the RetryTime speed I realized that increasing the time increases the speed/chance of hitting 0MB/s again. So what fixed it in my case was:

```
[Portal.BuildPatch]
ChunkDownloads=3
ChunkRetries=20
RetryTime=10.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to

`C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\EpicGamesLauncher\Saved\Config\Windows`

Edit `Engine.ini` (might be listed as `Engine`)

Add the following lines to the end of the file:

```
[Portal.BuildPatch] 
ChunkDownloads=3 ChunkRetries=20 RetryTime=0.5
```

Restart the Epic Launcher and restart your download.

Comment: I have already did that but still it stuck at 0. Then i tried downloading other games from epic and it seems only gta5 is the issue

Answer (score -2):

Possible errors:
Your hard drive is full
Error in game purchase
Solution if this doesnt work: restart download/update